# Stuck at for loop while ietrating over lists using os module in a function for tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, for-loop, tkinter

I am trying to create a Tkinter UI where you can browse on your system, select some files, and save the file paths in a list. These filepaths have filenames. Filenames have dates at the end or beginning. I call this new path.

Now I have another list of paths which I picked from excel. I call these old paths.

I am trying to replace old paths with new paths.

I am using `filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filepath)` to separate filenames from path. And then loop over both lists to check if the first 20 or last 20 characters of the name match, then I can save a list of `[new filepath, old filepath]` and export it to excel. But my loop is not working in `f3()` in the below code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
import openpyxl
import os

w = tk.Tk()
output_folder=r'C:\Users\filefolder'

def f1():
    #print('This will load parent file')
    global r
    global parentfilename
    global parentfilepath
    r = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("all files","*.*"),("excel file","*.xlsx")))
    parentfilename = os.path.basename(r)
    parentfilepath = os.path.normpath(r)
    messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "File Name Fetched")
    return parentfilepath

def f2():
    global z, new_z, name_z
    global q
    global oldfilepath
    xlApp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlsPath = parentfilepath
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath,ReadOnly=0,UpdateLinks=False)
    z = wb.LinkSources(win32com.client.constants.xlExcelLinks)
    z=list(z)
    oldfilepath =[os.path.normpath(link) for link in z]
    messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "Links Fethched from Parent File.")
    wb.Close()
    xlApp.Quit() 
    return new_z


def f3():
    global norm_y, match, m_df, df1, df2
    global newinputfilepath
    global newinputfilename
    global p
    global name, new
    newfilepath =[]
    match=[]

    y = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("all files","*.*"),("excel file","*.xlsx")))
    norm_y = os.path.normpath(y)
    newfilepath.append(os.path.normpath(norm_y))

    for i in newfilepath:
        for j in oldfilepath:
            if (os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(i))[0][:20] == os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(j))[0][:20]) or (os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(i))[0][-20:] == os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(j))[0][-20:0]):
                match.append([j,i])

                m_df = pd.DataFrame(match,columns=['OldInput_FilePath','NewInput_FilePath'])
                m_df['OldInput_FileName'] = m_df['OldInput_FilePath'].map(lambda a: os.path.basename(a))
                m_df['NewInput_FileName'] = m_df['NewInput_FilePath'].map(lambda a: os.path.basename(a))
                df1 = pd.DataFrame()
                df1 = m_df [['OldInput_FileName','NewInput_FileName']]
                df1.insert(0,'Parent_FileName',parentfilename)
                df2 = m_df[['OldInput_FilePath','NewInput_FilePath']]
                df2.insert(0,'Parent_FilePath',parentfilepath)
                with pd.ExcelWriter(poutput_folder+'\\'+'abc.xlsx') as writer:
                    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='FileNames',header= True, index=False)
                    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='FilePaths',header= True, index=False)

                    w.geometry('500x600')

                    spacelabel1 = tk.Label(w, text="        ")
                    spacelabel1.grid(row=0,)

                    label2 = tk.Label(w, height=1, width=15,text="Select Parent File") 
                    label2.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=1,padx=10, pady=10)

                    button3a=tk.Button(w, height=1, width=15,text="Parent File", command = f1)
                    button3a.grid(row=4,column=2,columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10)


                    label3 = tk.Label(w, height=1, width=15, text="Fetch Links From Parent File") 
                    label3.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=1,padx=10, pady=10)

                    button3b=tk.Button(w, height=1, width=15,text="OldFilePaths", command = f2)
                    button3b.grid(row=6,column=2,columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10)

                    label4 = tk.Label(w, height=1, width=15, text="Select New Files") 
                    label4.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=1,padx=10, pady=10)

                    button4=tk.Button(w, height=1, width=15, text="NewFilePaths", command = f3)
                    button4.grid(row=7,column=2,columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10)

                    label5 = tk.Label(w, height=1, width=15, text="Exit") 
                    label5.grid(row=20, column=1, columnspan=1,padx=10, pady=10)

                    button5 =tk.Button(w,height=1, width=15, text='Exit Program', command=w.destroy)
                    button5.grid(row=20,column=2,columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10)

                    spacelabel4 = tk.Label(w, text="        ")
                    spacelabel4.grid(row=21,padx=10, pady=30)

                    if __name__ == '__main__':
                        w.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'd recommend not editing your code to what it was, it's not readable

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What do you need help with?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  If I am running this code as whole and the for loop in f3 function is not working and match list is not appending. But if I run the code line by line, the list is appending.

Comment: @CodelikeBeaker Appreciate your effort. Your edit merged tkinter ui code  into its function. The program would not work.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I need to declare the list that needs to be appended outside the function.